# Maximum File Size on Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, downloads

I've uploaded two .rar files (3.0 Gb each) to ubuntu One (of course, I've got a +20Gb Plan),published at http://ubuntuone.com/p/pi0/ & http://ubuntuone.com/p/pi1/ .

Why does it show a 500 Internal Server when trying to download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Ubuntu One faqs indicates 5TB.
For detailed status of service report you can wacth this page:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status

Informations from:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhatIsTheLargestSizeFileICanSync

Comment: I suppose it is an error...I've submitted a ticket to the support service...TNX from Spain, Bud

Answer (score 3):

I have followed the link https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-is-the-largest-size-file-i-can-sync-with-ubuntu-one/

File size limit is 5TB sync. Is this a typo? I am having trouble finishing off 3.2Gb cannot imagine five terabytes!

Comment: haha lol. Once upon a time Ubuntu One gave 2 mbps but now i can't get more than 512 kbps -_-

Comment: So where to find the max file size that it can *handle*? Searching this for Ubuntu 12, but Ubuntu One should be much the same.